How can I use assimp's aiMeshMorphKey to animate a character's facial expressions?
I'm trying to implement facial expressions using morph animation in my 3D application. I've been looking into the assimp library and found the aiMeshMorphKey structure within the aiAnimation. Could you provide a code example demonstrating how to use aiMeshMorphKey to create morph animations, such as changing a character's facial expression over time?
    for (int i = 0; i < pAnimation->mNumMorphMeshChannels; ++i)
    {
        if (nodeName + "*0" == pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mName.C_Str())
        {
            std::map<float, glm::mat4> morphMeshKeys;
            for (int j = 0; j < pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mNumKeys; ++j)
            {
                std::cout << pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mName.data << std::endl;
                std::cout << pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mKeys[j].mTime << std::endl;
                std::cout << pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mKeys->mValues << std::endl;
                std::cout << pAnimation->mMorphMeshChannels[i]->mKeys->mWeights << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

Unfortunately, the official documentation was limited to this statement.
C_STRUCT aiMeshMorphAnim ** mMorphMeshChannels
The morph mesh animation channels.
Each channel affects a single mesh. The array is mNumMorphMeshChannels in size.

I have the same problem here, also trying to add facial animations :)
You should find within the meshes of your model one mesh (or more meshes) with mNumAnimMeshes greater than zero. The morph meshes are stored in the mAnimMeshes array of that mesh, having the same number of vertices as the main mesh.
Just blend the vertex positions (plus maybe normals, or whatever you need from the anim meshes) between the main mesh and the morph mesh(es).
Something like glm::mix(), or mix() in the GLSL shader should do the trick.
